# Translate some exercises from German to English

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-german

I need your help to translate some exercises from German to English.

> Für jede positive reelle Zahl a seien zwei Funktionen $f_a$ und $g_a$ durch die Gleichungen $y=f_a(x)=\sqrt{a-x}$ und $y=g_a(x)=\sqrt x - \sqrt a$ gegeben.
>
> a) Nennen Sie die größtmöglichen Definitionsbereiche der Funktionen $f_a$ und $g_a$!
>
> Gebben Sie für jede der Funktionen $f_a$ und $g_a$ die Koordinaten der gemeinsamen Punkte des Graphen mit den Koordinatenachsen an!
>
> Skizzieren Sie die Graphen der Funktionen $f_2$ und $g_2$ in ein und dasselbe Koordinatensystem!
>
> Beschreiben Sie, wie man den Graphen von $g_2$ aus dem Graphen von $f_2$ gewinnen kann!
>
> b) Die Graphen der Funktionen $f_a$ und $g_a$ sowie die $y$-Achse begrenzen ein Flächenstück vollständig. Berechnen Sie dessen Flächeninhalt!
>
> Die Tangente im Punkt $P_a(a;0)$ an den Graphen von $g_a$ teilt dieses Flächenstück in zwei Teilflächen.
>
> Berechnen Sie, in welchem Verhältnis die Inhalte dieser Teilflächen zueinander stehen!
>
> c) Der Graph der Funktion $g_a$ sowie die Koordinatenachsen begrenzen ein Flächenstück. Dieses Flächenstück rotiert um die $x$-Achse.
>
> Berechnen Sie das Volumen des dabei entstehenden Rotationskörpers!
>
> Nun rotiere dasselbe Flächenstück statt um die $x$-Achse um die Gerade mit der Gleichung $y=\sqrt a$.
>
> Ermitteln Sie auch das Volumen dieses Körpers!
>
> d) Die Punkte $O(0;0)$, $Q(r;0)$ und $R(r; f_a(r))$ bilden für jedes $r$ mit $0<r<a$ ein Dreieck.
>
> Untersuchen Sie, ob es einen Wert von $r$ gibt, für den der Flächeninhalt dieses Dreiecks maximal wird!
>
> Geben Sie einen ganzzahligen Wert von $a$ an, für den dieser maximale Flächeninhalt ebenfalls ganzzahlig ist!

Thanks :)

Comment: How about trying Wikipediacht; this really helped me pass my exam: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funktion_(Mathematik) , and follow the links; the context will help you learn some new terms. Of course, you also need to know the very basics of German grammar and vocabulary . There are free (freie) online German-English Diktionaren ( or something like that ).

Comment: Why not use google translate?

Comment: @Sergio Parreiras: It is not too good (yet?) for technical/specialized topics.

Comment: what about using google translate?

Comment: I am glad everybody is a smart guy using google translate. Shame on me, I am not able to use it! Have you tried? It is not so simple and useful with google translate!

Comment: Yes I have tried it, and the result is acceptable. google translate is better than one thinks, I mean you will certainly get the meaning of the exercise

Comment: I don't believe this should have been put on hold as off-topic. There is a [tag:translation-request] tag! I'm voting to reopen; discussion should probably occur on the [meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/if-is-it-possible-to-translate-some-exercises-from-german-to-english) opened by the OP.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For each positive real number $a$ let two functions $f_a$ and $g_a$ be given by the equations $y=f_a(x)=\sqrt{a-x}$ and $y=g_a(x)=\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}$.

1. Determine the largest possible domains of the functions $f_a$ and $g_a$. Give the $x$- and $y$-intercepts of each of the functions $f_a$ and $g_a$. Sketch the graphs of the functions $f_2$ and $g_2$ on the same set of coordinate axes. Describe how the graph of $g_2$ can be obtained from the graph of $f_2$.
2. The graphs of the functions $f_a$ and $g_a$ together with the $y$-axis completely bound a region; compute its area. The tangent to the graph of $g_a$ at the point $P_a(a,0)$ divides the region into two subregions. Compute the ratio between the areas of these subregions.
3. The graph of the function $g_a$ together with the coordinate axes bounds a region. This region rotates about the $x$-axis. Calculate the volume of the resulting solid of revolution. Now rotate the same region about the line $y=\sqrt{a}$ instead of about the $x$-axis. Determine the volume of this solid as well.
4. For each $r$ with $0<r<a$ the points $O(0,0)$, $Q(r,0)$, and $R(r,f_a(r))$ determine a triangle. Investigate whether there is a value of $r$ for which the area of this triangle is maximal. State an integer value of $a$ for which this maximal area is also an integer.

Comment: You mean with more translations? Probably, if it’s not too much. This is for the Abitur?

Comment: @Iuli: I can’t help with that, I’m afraid: I honestly don’t know what it covers.

Comment: now I want to ask you something about 3). is it ok what I did. 
$\cap Ox$, so $y=0$, $x=a$, $A(a,x)$. $\mbox{ }$

$\cap Oy$, so $x=0$, $y=\sqrt(a)$, $B(0,\sqrt{a})$

Now $$\mbox{Volume}=\pi\int^{a}_{0}{g_{a}^{2}(x)}\mbox{dx}$$?

Comment: @Iuli: Yes, that will give you the volume when the region is revolved about the $x$-axis (though you do want a $dx$ on the end).

Comment: Let me ask you another question about 3. When I have to rotate the same region about the line $y=\sqrt{a}$, the volume is $$\pi \int^{a}_{-a}{g^{2}_{a}}?$$ thanks!

Comment: @Iuli: No, now you have a washer whose outer radius is $R=\sqrt{a}-g_a(x)$ and whose inner radius is $r=\sqrt{a}$, so its area is $\pi(R^2-r^2)$.

Comment: What does "!" mean in German? Does it mark an imperative?

Comment: @dfeuer: That’s one of its uses, yes.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. I have read something today and I want to ask you something about the volume obtained rotating the same region about the line $y=\sqrt{a}.$ I make the intersection of the graph with $\cap Oy$ and I obtained the point $-\sqrt{a}$.  Now the volume is $$\int^{\sqrt{a}}_{-\sqrt{a}}{x^2\mbox{dy}}?$$ and then I make the substitution $x=(y+\sqrt{a})^{2}$. thanks!

Comment: @Iuli: No. If you’re integrating with respect to $y$, you’re getting cylindrical shells, not washers, the range of integration is from $y=-\sqrt{a}$ to $0$, and you won’t be squaring anything. If you integrate with respect to $x$, as in the earlier problem, the range of integration is from $x=0$ to $x=a$, the two $x$-extremes of the region. You get $$\pi\int_0^a\Big(\big(\sqrt{a}-g_a(x)\big)^2-\big(\sqrt{a}\big)^2\Big)dx\;.$$

Comment: I think in problem 2, "relationship" should be "ratio"

Comment: @Hagen: You’re right; thanks.

Comment: From where that substract $\sqrt{a}^2$? thanks!

Comment: @Iuli: The solid of revolution has a hole through its centre, and you have to remove that hole. [This](http://www2.bc.cc.ca.us/resperic/Math6A/Lectures/ch6/2/washer.htm) may help you to see what’s going on; it’s a little different, because it shows a region being revolved about the $x$-axis instead of a line parallel to the axis, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: @Iuli Please ask questions as questions, not as comments under answers to other questions.